# Win7 USB HubCV driver (xhci.sys) crash with BSOD

Tags: windows, usb, driver, bsod

In Win7 while running a tool (hubcv) for validating a usb hub for compliance, I get a BSOD with screen mentioning its driver's name (xhci.sys) and DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL error. What does this error mean? Does this signify a malfunction of the driver code or is it also possible that it is caused by the device under test?